# Reuse expression to select single

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-expressions

I have Property and PropertyCompliance entities that look something like this...

```
public class Property{
    public virtual ICollection<PropertyCompliance> ComplianceRecords {get;set;}
}

public class PropertyCompliance{
    public virtual Property {get;set;}
    public DateTime ComplianceDate {get;set;}
    public ComplianceRating ComplianceValue {get;set;} //just an enum
}
```

In a number of places I need to find the PropertyCompliance row closest to a particular date.

```
var complianceRating = property.ComplianceRecords.OrderBy(cr=>cr.Date)
    .Where(cr=>cr.ComplianceDate< checkDate).FirstOrDefault();
```

I know I could use an expression as such to filter the ComplianceRecords:

```
var complianceRating = property.ComplianceRecords.Where(SomeExpression)
    .OrderBy(cr=>cr.ComplianceDate).FirstOrDefault()
```

However this isn't really reducing the amount of repetition as all it's doing is replacing the Where() statement.

Is there a way to apply the expression to the Property to allow this filtering to occur within another expression? Something like:

```
private static Expression<Func<Property, ComplianceRating>> PropertyComplianceForDate(DateTime checkDate)
{
    return p => p.ComplianceRatings
         .OrderByDescending(cr => cr.Date)
         .First(cr => cr.Date <= checkDate).ComplianceRating;
}


public Expression<Func<Property, bool>> PropertyIsCompliant(DateTime checkDate)
{
    return (p) => PropertyComplianceForDate(checkDate) == ComplianceRating.Compliant;
}
```

With "PropertyComplianceForDate" being an expression that could be translated to SQL to allow the PropertyIsCompliant expression to be used in SQL also.

Comment: This should be possible in the next version of entity framework. This pull request was accepted into entity framework yesterday, which implements what you are describing: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/forks/BrandonDahler/EntityFramework/contribution/7352#!/tab/comments. Basically this checks whether a method within an expression returns an expression before deciding whether to execute or convert to sql. If you need to use this now, it should be possible with nightly builds: http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Nightly%20Builds

Comment: Do you always need a record from one `Property` or do you want a list of `Properties` all having this one record (or none) loaded in one query? Or can we assume properties always have all their `ComplianceRecords` loaded?

Comment: The "PropertyIsCompliant" expression will be used against a list of properties in the database. var compliantProperties = db.Properties.Where(PropertyIsCompliant);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare an expression at class level and reuse it.

Alternatively you could make a method on your table or an extension method. Extension method (inside a static class) would look something like:

```
public static PropertyCompliance PropertyIsCompliant(this IEnumerable<PropertyCompliance> complianceRecords, DateTime checkDate) {
    return complianceRatings
         .OrderByDescending(cr => cr.Date)
         .First(cr => cr.Date <= checkDate);
}
```

Comment: If I use an extension method as above, it won't be able to be converted to SQL when used in an expression. I've tried having a similar method on the Property class it's self and as before, it cannot be converted to SQL when used in another expression.

Comment: You'd call *tableName*.PropertyIsCompliant(date) or *query*.PropertyIsCompliant(date). It should translate to SQL. Have you tried it?

Comment: The issue is that I have the PropertyIsCompliance expression which is fine if it contains the logic for selecting the correct ComplianceRecord. I have other expressions that rely on that same date selection logic. So I want to have that all in 1 place. Instead of duplicated in each compliance expression.

Comment: That already works.
The PropertyIsCompliant expression relies on getting the most applicable ComplianceRecord for a partcicular property for a date. I ALSO have PropertyHasWarnings PropertyIsFailure etc... Each of these require the same logic to get the ComplianceRecord to check. I want to pull that ComplianceRecord selecting logic into an expression that can be shared with the other compliance expressions.